# Signing with temporary credentials for API gateway request problems

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to invoke my API Gateway with authenticated users with the REST API. For this I'm using: [Cognito UserPool + Cognito Identity Pool + API Gateway + AWS_IAM Authorization + Cognito Credentials](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=230452). From what I've gathered I need to sign my request with (temporary credentials). Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28479138/how-can-one-make-authenticated-requests-with-aws-cognito-from-mobile-to-aws-serv) I want to sign my request with the following keys:

```
{
 SecretKey: '', 
 AccesKeyId: '',
 SessionKey: ''
}
```

If I use an associated user from my IAM console and use the corresponding SecretKey + AccesKeyID everything works fine. However, I want to use the **Unauthenticated and Authenticated roles from my Identity Pools** to apply IAM policies based on authenticated or unauthenticated users. 
FYI: I can call the authenticated functions from [this part of the documentation.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-ios-sdk.html)

I'm building a React-Native app, and because of that I want to keep the native SDK to a minimum and I'm only using `AWSCognitoIdentityProvider` part. For the user handling.

I trying to receive the correct keys using this Objective-C code:

```
 [[self.credentialsProvider credentials] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
    if (task.error) {
      NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
    }
    else {
      AWSCredentials *response = task.result;

      NSString *accessKey = response.accessKey;
      NSString *secretKey = response.secretKey;
      NSString *sessionKey = response.sessionKey;
      NSDictionary *responseData = @{
                                     @"AccessKey" : accessKey,
                                     @"SecretKey" : secretKey,
                                     @"SessionKey": sessionKey
                                     };
        }

    return nil;
  }];
```

The rest I've setup using the [relevant docs.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-ios-sdk.html)

I (wrongly?) tried to sign my requests with the
*AccessKey*, *SecretKey*, *SessionKey* retrieved from the *CredentialsProvider* above.

```
  {
     SecretKey: credentials.SecretKey, 
     AccesKeyId: credentials.AccessKey,
     SessionKey: credentials.SessionKey
   }
```

The signing fails with the following error:

```
{ message: 'The security token included in the request is invalid.' }
```

So the question I have is: which keys should I use to sign my requests for authenticated users so that I can apply the attached IAM policies from my Cognito Setup?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: `SessionKey`?  Not `SessionToken`?

Answer (score 0):

Like Michael - sqlbot, point out, it should be **SessionToken** instead of **SessionKey**. I found a better instruction on [how to get credentials from **Cognito**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html).